# Dynamic .htaccess 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

Currently, about half of our webpages derive from our **HTML_page.php**.

I want to add a `<div class="Error404">` tag, **404 div**, there to display 404 error information.

If a non-**HTML_page.php** webpages triggers a 404 error, I cannot display an error message using my **404 div**.

> **UPDATE:** A non-HTML_page.php would be any of our older, legacy pages that do not yet inherit from our "HTML_page.php" base class and all external websites that link to items on our domain that may not exist.

So, the default structure still needs the 404 routed to our `404.php` page, but modify the routing **if** I can detect that the webpage contains my **404 div**.

Here is how our `.htaccess` page starts out now:

```
# Custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /eForms/404Form.php

#
# Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

#
# Rewrite rule for document secuity
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$ /docgateway.php?source=$1.pdf [L,NC,QSA]
```

This snippet of [jQuery's hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) illustrates the logic I want:

```
if ($("div").hasClass("Error404")) {
```

Is there any way to build that type of logic into the **.htaccess** file for the **ErrorDocument**?

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by `If a non-HTML_page.php webpages triggers a 404 error,`? Is there any rule to send most of these pages to `/HTML_page.php` file?

Comment: All of our new webpages derive from **HTML_page.php**. Older pages with lots of specialized code do not, and anything on our site that is linked with an external site obviously does not.

Comment: The thing is that mod_rewrite cannot detect presence of any DIV tag. It can only work on URI, QUERY_STRING, COOKIES, HEADERS, SERVER info etc

Comment: Would it be possible if I had my **HTML_page.php** set a SERVER variable?

Comment: Yes it would be possible if `HTML_page.php` sends a certain HTTP header in the request